# Pass a value from controller as JSON in codeigniter to view that contain on Angular Js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, codeigniter, autocomplete

I need to use this:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/angular

but my problem when I try to change the url to:

```
read: {
        url: base_url+"index.php/welcome/findAll",
}
```

and the function `findAll` in controller contain on:

```
public function findAll()
{
    $listproduct = $this->mproduct->findAll();
    echo json_encode($listproduct);
}
```

The list of options become empty.

Comment: Does /findAll provide you valid json?

Comment: Yes but the angularjs can't read the value . it just read xml in the example. but I want to pass value from database as json

Answer (score 0):

You controller seems to be fine as long as it returns a valid JSON format.. in your AngularJS controller try doing:

```
 $scope.MyFunction = function() 
 {
    console.log("posting data....");

    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://domain/controller/method_that_return_json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data : JSON.stringify({What you want to return from JSON here})
    }).success(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Another aproach:

```
 $http.get("http://www.domain.com/pathtojson)
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.related = response;
    });
}
```